# Python/Numpy compress methode issue

Tags: python, numpy

*NumPy is the fundamental package for scientific computing with Python. It contains among other things:
    a powerful N-dimensional array object
    sophisticated (broadcasting) functions
    tools for integrating C/C++ and Fortran code
    useful linear algebra, Fourier transform, and random number capabilities*

i need to know what is the utility of compress methode and how the numbers converting is done ?

```
from pylab import *
from time import time,sleep
import sys
import argparse
from math import *
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,9,6,97987978978977987987897987987])
y=fromstring(x,'uint16')
time=compress(y&0x8000==1,y)
print(time)
print(x)
```

how does it work this procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually calling the `numpy` function [compress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html) (from the namespace of `pylab` I believe).

This is kind of indexation function that allows you to return selected indexes of an array. Looking at the example in the documentation you will see:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> np.compress([0, 1], a, axis=0)
array([[3, 4]])
```

Considering the axis is 0 (rows) the return was the second row (I believe the condition to be equivalent to `[False, True]`).

In your particular case you seem to be giving a condition to return `y` only when:

```
[32768     0     0     0 32768     0     0     0 32768     0     0     0
 32768     0     0     0 32768     0     0     0 32768     0     0     0
 32768     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
```

`==1`, which only you can tell the significance (`y&0x8000`).

**EDIT:** Using your own example I'll print your condition, `time` as you made it, and time with a new condition which has `True` values:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,9,6,97987978978977987987897987987])
y=fromstring(x,'uint16')
print('Your condition: ',y&0x8000==1)
time=compress(y&0x8000==1,y)
print('Your test: ',time)
time=compress(y&0x8000==0,y)
print('Test with True values in condition: ',time)
```

This returns:

```
Your condition:  [False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False]
Your test:  []
Test with True values in condition:  [7652    0    0 7652    0    0 7652    0    0 7652    0    0 7652    0    0
 7652    0    0 7652    0    0 8920 1114    0    0]
```

Comment: <code> &0x8000 </code> numbers having the same representation, in binary 1000 0000 0000 0000 (0x8000 )

Comment: @Cod3r I would suppose so although it's not something I'm acquainted to. In any case it seems the condition you are inserting will return an array of `False` (and I guess the output for `time` will be empty).

Comment: why it's empty the array Of time

Comment: and when he will be not empty ?

Comment: @Cod3r Because the condition `y&0x8000==1` returns an array of `False` meaning no index in the `y` array is to be returned. I'll edit the answer to use your data.

Comment: and if we Do just y&0x8000 whit out ==1 or ==0 what it should be returned

Comment: @Cod3r That is exactly the example I've used in my edit. The returns are there also. One (==1) comes out empty, the other (==0) returns the positions of `y` where condition is `True`.

Comment: y=fromstring(x,'uint64')                                                                                 x=np.array([1,2,5686402150554,654,564,897,16,897,156,789,12,89,15678,486])   comp =compress(x&0x8000,x) he return just 5686402150554 Why

Comment: @Cod3r Because condition `x&0x8000` is probably zero (False) everywhere except in the third position (that if is not zero it's assumed to be `True`). So if you print `x&0x8000` you should have something like `[False,False, True, ..., False]`.

Comment: @Cod3r You are welcome.